# Polynomials with a given property

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials, functional-equations

Find all polynomials with real coefficients such that
$$xp(x) + yp(y)\geq2p(xy)$$ for all $x, y\in\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt:

I noticed the similarity between the given expression and the square of the sum
$$(x-y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2xy\geq0$$
So I guessed that $p$ would be of the form $$p(x)=ax$$ and I found that $a>0$. I tried to do $p(x)=ax\cdot q(x) + r$ to proof that $p(x)=ax$ would be the only solution, but I didn't finish this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Does this AoPS thread answer your question? (the answer is in a spoiler box) https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1558277p9514902 - found using [Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24xp(x)%20%2B%20yp(y)%5Cgeq2p(xy)%24&p=1)